# How to integrate a simple piecewise function with sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to get the Rayleigh distribution's CDF by integrating its PDF:

[image: PDF]

Following the formula:

[image: formula]

The expected result should be:

[image: CDF]

This is the code I tried:

```
import sympy as smp

x, s, y, z, u, v, w = smp.symbols('x, s, y, z, u, v, w', real=True)
expr = smp.Piecewise((s*smp.E**((-s**2)/2),smp.StrictGreaterThan(s, 0)), (0, smp.LessThan(s, 0)))
res = smp.integrate(expr, (s, -(smp.oo), x))
```

which contains:

[image: wrong]

While if not treating it as a piecewise, with code:

```
import sympy as smp

x, s, y, z, u, v, w = smp.symbols('x, s, y, z, u, v, w', real=True)
expr = s*smp.E**((-s**2)/2)
res = smp.integrate(expr, (s, -(smp.oo), x), manual=True)
```

The result is:

[image: res wrong]

How can I get the correct result with sympy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declare `x` as positive (rather than just real) then it will simplify.

```
In [22]: expr
Out[22]: 
⎧     2            
⎪   -s             
⎪   ────           
⎨    2             
⎪s⋅ℯ      for s > 0
⎪                  
⎩   0     otherwise

In [23]: x = symbols('x', real=True)

In [24]: integrate(expr, (s, -oo, x))
Out[24]: 
           2       2 
 -Min(0, x)      -x  
 ────────────    ────
      2           2  
ℯ             - ℯ    

In [25]: x = symbols('x', positive=True)

In [26]: integrate(expr, (s, -oo, x))
Out[26]: 
       2 
     -x  
     ────
      2  
1 - ℯ
```

Comment: Thanks, I had just reached a similar solution on my own, this integral should start from 0 and not from -oo given that x is positive.